# Strange errors when changing out the sprite

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, phaser-framework

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

//creating score value and onscreen text
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function preload() {
    // preload assets
    game.load.image('sky', 'assets/img/sky.png');
    game.load.image('ground', 'assets/img/platform.png');
    game.load.image('star','assets/img/star.png');
    game.load.spritesheet('baddie', 'assets/img/baddie.png', 32, 48);
}

function create() {
    // place your assets
    //enabling Arcade Physics system
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    //adding a background
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');

    //a group containing the ground and platforms to jump on
    platforms = game.add.group();

    //enabling physics for any object in this group
    platforms.enableBody = true;

    //creating the ground
    var ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 64, 'ground');

    //scaling to fit the width of the game
    ground.scale.setTo(2, 2);

    //stops ground from falling once player jumps on it
    ground.body.immovable = true;

    //create five ledges
    var ledge = platforms.create(-300, 400, 'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;
    ledge = platforms.create(200, 400, 'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;
    ledge = platforms.create(100, 300, 'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;
    ledge = platforms.create(-200, 200, 'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;
    ledge = platforms.create(300, 100, 'ground');
    ledge.body.immovable = true;

    //create the player and its settings
    player = game.add.sprite(32, game.world.height - 150, 'baddie');

    //enabling physics on player
    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

    //giving player a slight bounce
    player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
    player.body.gravity.y = 300;
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    //walking left and right animations
    player.animations.add('left', [0, 1], 10, true);
    player.animations.add('right', [2, 3], 10, true);

    //create group for stars
    stars = game.add.group();
    stars.enableBody = true;

    //creating 12 stars evenly spaced apart
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        //create a star inside of the 'stars' group each 33 px apart
        var star = stars.create(i * 33, 0, 'star');

        //giving it gravity
        star.body.gravity.y = 6;

        //giving each star a random bounce value
        star.body.bounce.y = 0.7 + Math.random() * 0.2;
    }
    scoreText = game.add.text(16, 16, 'Score: 0', {fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000'});
}

function update() {
    // run game loop
    //collide player and stars with platforms
    var hitPlatform = game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);

    //built in keyboard manager
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    //reset players velocity (movement)
    player.body.velocity.x = 0;

    //moving with arrow keys
    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        //move to left
        player.body.velocity.x = -150;
        player.animations.play('left');
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        //move right
        player.body.velocity.x = 150;
        player.animations.play('right');
    }
    else {
        //stand still
        player.animations.stop();
        player.frame = 2;
    }

    //allow player to jump if touching ground
    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down && hitPlatform) {
        player.body.velocity.y = -350;
    }

    //checking for collision with stars and platforms
    game.physics.arcade.collide(stars, platforms);

    //checking if player overlaps with star
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);
}

function collectStar (player,star) {

    //removes star from screen
    star.kill();

    //add and update score
    score += 10;
    scoreText.text = 'Score: ' + score;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why, but once I changed the sprite (which has fewer animation frames than the original), some strange errors popped up. The two error messages say:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFrameIndexes' of null

Uncaught ReferenceError: stars is not defined

The animation frame ranges don't seem to go out of bounds and I've already defined my 'stars' variable in the create function. Any ideas on why I'm getting these weird error messages? (the spirtesheet of the player is attached below)

[image: spritesheet]

Comment: which browser is it?

Comment: @darkangel: I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i answer,

The error says **Uncaught ReferenceError: stars is not defined**

I think you have to declare **stars** as a global variable because you use it in create() and update(), but becarefull with the local defintion of it in collectStar()